# After inserting new data to linked list, can't deleting any data from new linked list

Tags: linked-list

I am creating a `linked-list` and displaying the data list as sorted format.All are working fine. Deletion part also work when I don't insert new data into it. I mean, when I skip the `insert` part. But when I am going to work with `insert` part also.Then, it's saying - `(data) Not Found to delete!`. I can't understand why it's happening? Where in I am going wrong would someone help to find out this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *createLinkedList(int n);
void displayList(node *head);
void sortedList(node *head);
void search(node *head, int data);
void insert(node *head, int data);
void deleteNode(node *head, int data);
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    int sr = 0;
    node *head = NULL;
    printf("\nHow many nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    head = createLinkedList(n);
    sortedList(head);
    displayList(head);

    printf("\nEnter the value you want to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    deleteNode(head, n);
    displayList(head);

    printf("\nEnter the new value to insert: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    insert(head, n);
    sortedList(head);
    displayList(head);

    printf("\nEnter the value to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    search(head, n);

    return 0;
}

node *createLinkedList(int n){
    int i = 0;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("\nEnter the data for node number %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &(temp->data));

        //if list is currently empty
        if(head == NULL){
            head = temp;
        }else{
            p = head;
            while(p->next != NULL){
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }

    return head;
}

void displayList(node *head){
    node *p = head;

    while(p != NULL){
         printf("\t%d", p->data);
         p = p->next;
    }
}

void sortedList(node *head){
    int temp;
    node *i, *j;
    printf("\nThe sorted data list is: \n");
    for(i = head; i->next != NULL; i = i->next){
        for(j = i->next; j != NULL; j = j->next){
            if(i->data > j->data){
                temp = i->data;
                i->data = j->data;
                j->data = temp;
            }
         }
     }
}

void search(node *head, int data){
     int count = 0;
     while(head->next != NULL){
         if(head->next->data == data){
             count++;
         }
         head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\nTotal %d results found for %d\n", count, data);
}

void insert(node *head, int data){
    while(head->next != NULL){
        head = head->next;
    }
    head->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    head->next->data = data;
    head->next->next = NULL;

    printf("\nAfter inserting %d", data);
}
void deleteNode(node *head, int data){
    while(head->next != NULL){
        if(head->next->data == data){
            head->next = head->next->next;
            return 0;
        }
        if(head->next->data != data){
            printf("\n%d Not Found to delete! \n", data);
            return 0;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\nAfter delete %d", data);
}
```

Comment: If your delete function is marked as returning void, then you should not be returning 0s from the function. Simply `return;` will work.

Comment: Another issue I'm having with your code is that in your `createLinkedList` function you do not set the value of `temp->next` to `NULL` which results in undefined behavior. After making the changes I mentioned, I am not having the same issue you are describing. What specific input are you trying?

Comment: Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to see where the error occurs?

Comment: reordering the call sequence in `main()` is just masking the underlying problem.  Also, when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: You have the authority to close your own question.  We do not (except via a number down votes)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asked us to close this question.

Comment: Closing your question will not prevent you getting downvotes. Edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 2):

In deleteNode function, you are checking the second element and if that is not the data which needs to be deleted, you print out "Not found to delete" and exit from the function. Hence, data you want to delete is not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In *createLinkedList(); function you are not assigning value to next pointer(it's a wild pointer) of temp and just reading data into temp->data